# Is using Fragment as an Activity possible in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

I made fragments in my Kotlin project and now I wanna fill them. But in the .kt file there's some codes that I didn't see in activitys. Can I code that .kt file in fragment like I'm coding an activity, or is it gonna make a problem?

Comment: There are more boiler-plate code in fragment than activity in android studio but you can remove all those code and can have only one or two method.

Comment: But when I try to add findViewById or setContentView it's giving error. Can't I use them in fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments have just some different [lifecycle methods](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) to be aware of.

[image]

If you want to use findViewById for instance you can use it inside `onViewCreated`.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id)
}
```